# Zend_Date subtraction of two datetime mysql values

Tags: zend-framework, zend-date, php

i am building a small application to calculate employee attendance.

A user will check in, his check in time will be recorded in a mysql datetime format, for example

```
check_in_time 2011-12-16 20:27:20
```

And when he checks out

```
check_out_time 2011-12-16 20:27:27
```

I can do it the conventional way by exploding and doing the subtraction, but am sure Zend_Date has a more efficient way of doing it.

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.date.overview.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously my question was not hard to answer, anyhow this is the answer to get the time diff in seconds, then i can handle seconds normally.

Thanks for the docs @ajreal, i did not look correctly into them.

```
public function getTimeInSeconds($dateStart, $dateEnd) {
    $dateStart = new Zend_Date($dateStart);
    $dateEnd = new Zend_Date($dateEnd);
    $new = $dateStart->sub($dateEnd);
    $timeInSeconds = $new->getTimestamp();
    return $timeInSeconds;
}
```